# Does git stash saves code for all times or only until the next garbage colleciton?

Tags: git, implementation

Some colleges and i discussed about the implementation of git stash.
Some colleges says that git stash saves code in the same way as saved in a branch, but without a branch. 
I thought until now, that git stash saves the code only until the next garbage collection and the garbage collection deletes this code then.

Because its very important for me, how git stash is working, i am asking.

Answer (score 0):

In short, stash entries are permanent references, they *do* prevent garbage collection. The objects they reference will only be garbage collected when the entries themsleves are dropped (`git stash drop <entry>`) or the list itself is cleared (`git stash clear`).